# Можно ли считать заново сумму в оконной функции при встрече определенного значения? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Исходная таблица:

| Имя | Дата | Присутствие |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Вася | 01.01.2021 | 0 |
| Вася | 02.01.2021 | 0 |
| Вася | 03.01.2021 | 1 |
| Вася | 04.01.2021 | 1 |
| Вася | 05.01.2021 | 0 |

Необходимо получить:

| Имя | Дата | Присутствие | Пропусков подряд |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Вася | 01.01.2021 | 0 | 1 |
| Вася | 02.01.2021 | 0 | 2 |
| Вася | 03.01.2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Вася | 04.01.2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Вася | 05.01.2021 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Можно. Конкретно эта задача - типичная "gaps and islands".